# New process type not starting executable

Tags: peoplesoft

I am attempting to add a Bash shell process type to one of my environments. This bash script updates the process tables and then executes whatever is passed into it.

- The Operating system and DB type match my system. Type set to "Other." The command line and parameter fields are set.
- I have added the type to "Process Types run on this Server" for my server entry with the same priority as all the other, and max occurance = 1 (no other processes are running in this dev env)
- I have added a process, API aware, added a component and appended additional parameters "echo test"
- "Process Output Type Settings" has web set for "other"

I start the process, it appears in the process monitor as "queued" but never progresses. But if I copy the command line in "Process Request Parameters" and run it manually on the app server, it works and shows success in the process monitor. However it doesn't post the Log/Trace. Additionally there is no change if I try to make the process not Api aware. As I understand it should at least change to successful after it starts the command line process.

Why would the actual command line process not start? What causes the process to post a Log/Trace? How can I debug this? What else can I troubleshoot?

Comment: [Defining Process Definitions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tprs/task_DefiningProcessDefinitions-c0710f.html): Selecting [API Aware] does not mean that the process becomes API-aware. You must still add API code to the process. Did you restart the batch server after adding the process type? If your process is queued in process monitor, does it have a reasonable run date? The process should only go to 'Processing' when the run date is reached.

Comment: @PeterPaff I have code to update the psprcsque and psprcsrqst tables, this works when I start the executable manually. The run date is set to the time that I started the process. I am not familiar with restarting the batch server, how is this done?